# subviews in annotation view not detecting touch events

Tags: ios, ipad, mkannotationview

I have a big problem. I've subclassed `MKAnnotationView` and added three `UIImageViews` each one with an image. The annotations look fine on the map. However, they don't capture touch events. I've tried everything around `self.userInteractionEnabled` and `exclusiveTouch` but nothing seems to work.

- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id )annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
  {

  ```
  self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
  self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kWidth, kHeight);


  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"geo-icon.png"];

  UIImageView * turbineView = [ [ UIImageView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height) ];

  UIImageView * mastroView = [ [ UIImageView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 100.0, image.size.width, image.size.height) ];
  mastroView.image = image;
  mastroView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
  mastroView.exclusiveTouch = NO;


  [turbineView addSubview:mastroView];

  image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"turbine-noshadow.png"];
  propellerView = [ [ UIImageView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4.0, 82.0, image.size.width, image.size.height) ];
  propellerView.image = image;
  propellerView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
  propellerView.exclusiveTouch = NO;
  [turbineView addSubview:propellerView];

  image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];
  UIImageView * arrowView = [ [ UIImageView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(32.0, 114.0, image.size.width, image.size.height) ];
  arrowView.image = image;
  arrowView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
  arrowView.exclusiveTouch = NO;
  [turbineView addSubview:arrowView];

  image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"run-turbine.png"];
  UIImageView * stoprunView = [ [ UIImageView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65.0, 155.0, image.size.width, image.size.height) ];
  stoprunView.image = image;
  stoprunView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
  stoprunView.exclusiveTouch = NO;
  [turbineView addSubview:stoprunView];
  turbineView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
  turbineView.exclusiveTouch = NO;




  [self addSubview:turbineView];
  self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
  self.exclusiveTouch = NO;
  self.opaque = NO;

  [self rodar];  //
  return self;
  ```

}

Comment: please post code containing the views for context

Comment: The annotations represent eolic turbines with the propellers spinning through an animation. Each UIImageView has an image of a part of the turbine. The UIImageView with the propeller image rotate. Here is the code:

Answer (score 0):

Use MKMapViewDelegate's `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:` to detect when the user taps on an annotation rather than trying to interact with taps on the annotation itself.

You can figure out which of your annotations was selected and take the appropriate action from `mapView:didSelect...`.

Comment: The problem is that mapView:didSelectAnnotationView isn't being called.